# Loop over csv and subtract previous line from current line?

Tags: python, csv

My csv file looks something like this:

```
month,amount
jan,1
feb,3
mar,4
apr,7
may,9
```

I need to get the current row - previous row and get the average from the total sum. Please see below:

```
month,amount
jan,1
feb,3    3-1 = 2
mar,4    4-3 = 1
apr,7    7-4 = 3
may,9    9-7 = 2

Average (2,1,3,2)
```

Here is what I have so far, but I am getting the error message `ValueError: Invalid Literal for Int() with base 10`.

```
with open("budget_data2.csv", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
output = []
#header = lines[4]
data = [int(number) for number in lines[1:]]
for index, number in enumerate(data[1:],1):
    output.append(number-data[index-1])
print(output)
print("Average: {}".format(sum(output)/len(output)))
```

Comment: You're not splitting the line at the comma.

Comment: Read [module-csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv)

Answer (score 2):

You need to split each line at the comma. You can use the `csv` module to parse CSV files automatically.

```
import csv
with open("budget_data2.csv", "r") as f:
    rows = csv.DictReader(f)
    data = [int(row['amount']) for row in rows]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas like this (pip install pandas):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
data = """
month,amount
jan,1
feb,3
mar,4
apr,7
may, 9
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data),sep=',')
# dif
df['dif']=df[['amount']].diff()
print(df)
# average
print(df["dif"].mean())
```

Result :

```
  month  amount  dif
0   jan       1  NaN
1   feb       3  2.0
2   mar       4  1.0
3   apr       7  3.0
4   may       9  2.0

2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, consider the other answers to improve your Python coding skills. But if you wish to continue the way you were going, take out the `\n` charachters (newline) and split the lines using the character comma `,` as a delimiter. When using `split` function, it returns a list of the "parts" of the string when you split by the commas.

Then access the clean data. In code:

```
with open("budget_data2.csv", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

data = []

for line in lines[1:]: #don't read the first line containing month and amount
    line = line.strip("\n") #erase the newline character from each line
    data.append(line.split(",")) #split the lines using the comma as a delimiter

output = []
for index,element in enumerate(data[1:]): #we start in the second element because we will subtract the first one
    output.append(int(element[1])-int(data[index][1]))

average = sum(output)/len(output)

print(output)
print(average)
```

Result:

```
[2, 1, 3, 2]
2.0
```